# Solution for a pay-per-view type website that locks some users from info, unless they have a subscription

Tags: cms, ecommerce

I've been combing the net for the past 3 days trying to find a solution to a unique problem my client is having. They want to build a wiki type website that houses the following features:

- Private section where users can purchase access to files/information
- Supports multiple users
- Public locked from editing wiki/article pages
- Is not self-hosted (Software as a service (SaaS))
- Is a managed service, updates/security/etc. are handled by service
- Does not have ads (can be overlooked if platform is really good)
- We own the content
- Easy to add content, with templates or something similar

There are several wiki services out there, Wikia.com and Wikispaces.com are pretty nice and easy to use. But there is no way to lock pages by a subscription or anything like that. Unless I'm missing something, I don't think this can be achieved via a SaaS.

So that brings me to alternatives. If I can convince them to use something like MediaWiki on a shared server, it would open up my options. I can't find any plugins for MediaWiki that allow for the PPV either though.

I'm beginning to think this whole idea of a "wiki" isn't really what they are looking for, since they mainly just want internal staff to edit the content. This led me into knowledgebase software, but I still cannot locate any type of "pay-per-view" type content locking that they need.

I can probably achieve something like this with a WordPress install and a mass of plugins, but that's very messy and requires someone on staff to make sure the site stays healthy and updated.

As you can probably tell, I'm very lost. Does anyone know of any type of service/software that would assist me in finding a solution to these issues?

Comment: MediaWiki does allow ACL, though in a limited way; see e.g. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown You could alter user groups based on the payments, for which there is also some MediaWiki extension (like DonationInterface).

Comment: Indeed, I doubt a wiki is required. I suggest you extend your search to blogs (and [edit] the question accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

If you won't have any sufficient SaaS wiki, try think about Drupal. Drupal is good equipped for user-accesses and for paying-for-something.

There are some modules for making wiki with Drupal: try https://www.drupal.org/search/site/wiki

But there are plenty other ways in Drupal, how to organize editing of the content by many people.